# Get log message from Assertions

Tags: java, selenium, testng, extentreports

I'm integrating html-reports to our test framework using Extent Report library (version 4).

For that purpose I wrote a wrapper, that encapsulates our default TestNG logger (for the console output) and ExtentReport logger (ExtentTest.log, to collect data for html-report). 
We use TestNg as our testing framework.

Having an issue capturing log messages from failed assertions (both soft and hard Assertions) to display it in html-report, they go only to the console log.
What would be the possible solution to capture those Assert log messages to show them in html-report?

I can't extend Assert (or SoftAssert) classes and add my own implementation (by adding an instance of ExtentTest.log there) because I'd have to replace all assertions in dozens of tests.

```
public class Loggers {
  private static final Loggers instance = new Loggers();
  private static ExtentTest test;
  private static ExtentReports extent;
  private static Logger LOG;
  private static final String REPORT_LOCATION = "test-output/reports.extent.html";

  /**
   * Returns an instance of {@link ExtentReports} object. If it doesn't exist creates a new instance and returns it
   */
  public static ExtentReports getLogger() {
    if ( extent == null ) {
      createInstance();
    }
    return extent;
  }

  /**
   * Create ExtentReport and attaches htmlReporter to it
   */
  public static void createInstance() {
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = getHTMLReporter();
    extent = new ExtentReports();
    extent.attachReporter( htmlReporter );
  }

  /**
   * This method creates, configures and returns an instance of ExtentHtmlReporter
   *
   */
  public static ExtentHtmlReporter getHTMLReporter() {
    ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter( REPORT_LOCATION );
     return htmlReporter;
  }

  /**
   * This method logs a message with the INFO level for both instances of TestNG Logger and ExtentTest
   */
  public void info( String message ) {
    LOG.info( message );
    test.log( Status.INFO, message );
  }
```

Comment: The easiest way to do is by using the testng-adapter for version 4: https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-testng-adapter. It does everything without writing any code, by simply using the listener construct via testng.xml or annotation the class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution. Will post here if somebody will have similar issue.

If you locate your loggers in a listener class, you can put your logger over there and use ITestResult as an argument, specifically its method getThrowable (It returns the throwable that was thrown while running the method)

```
 /**
   * Triggered upon the failure of a test
   */
  public void onTestFailure( ITestResult testResult ) {
      LOG.fail( testResult.getThrowable() );
 }
```

It will print in the report a failed assertion or thrown exception.

Comment: You should perhaps accept your answer so that the question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

The Below Code Works for me for Extent Report Try it!

1) Initialize Extent report and Logger

```
public static Logger log = Logger.getLogger("devpinoyLogger");
public ExtentReports rep = ExtentManager.getInstance();
public static ExtentTest test;
```

2) Use Configuration File ReportsConfig.xml for Extent Report that you can get from extentreports official site.

3) Create class ExtentManager that load config file and set output of Extent report file.

```
   public class ExtentManager {

        private static ExtentReports extent;
        public static ExtentReports getInstance(){

            if(extent==null){
                System.out.println("Path of user DIR"+System.getProperty("user.dir"));
                extent = new ExtentReports(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\target\\surefire-reports\\ExecutionReport.html",true,DisplayOrder.OLDEST_FIRST);
                extent.loadConfig(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\src\\main\\java\\extentconfig\\ReportsConfig.xml"));       
            }
            return extent;
        }
    }
```

4) Use INFO and ERROR log in method you are creating to display logs in Extent report.

```
public void click(String xpath) {

    try {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(Variables.OR.getProperty(xpath))).click();
        System.out.println(xpath + "Button clicked");
        test.log(LogStatus.INFO, xpath + " Button clicked");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Cannot Click " + e.getMessage());
        test.log(LogStatus.ERROR,"Unable to click on :: " + xpath + " Button");
        throw new AssertionError("Unable to click on ::  " + xpath + " Button", e);
    }
}
```

5) Use Custom listener class CustomListeners

```
public class CustomListeners extends TestBase implements ITestListener, ISuiteListener {

public boolean flag;

..implement all methods of CustomListeners class and use logs in onTestSuccess and onTestFailure Methods.

public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult arg0) {

    test.log(LogStatus.PASS, arg0.getName().toUpperCase() + " PASS");
    rep.endTest(test);
    rep.flush();

}


public void onTestFailure(ITestResult arg0) {
    System.out.println(arg0 + " =================Test Case Failed===========================");
    flag = true;
    System.out.println("Flag is inside onTestFailure " + flag);
    System.setProperty("org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output", "false");

    try {
        test.log(LogStatus.FAIL, arg0.getName().toUpperCase() + " Failed with exception : " + arg0.getThrowable());
        rep.endTest(test);
        rep.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("IOException occurs " + e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

- ExtentReport view for PASS Test Case

[image]

- ExtentReport view for FAIL Test Case

[image]

Comment: I would highly recommend upgrading to version 4 and using the extentreports-testng-listener so you can avoid writing all the scaffolding code in this post.